# Move showModalBottomSheet to the top

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to move showModalBottomSheet 75pixels to the top so it doesnt block my bottom menu? I tried to give my Container padding but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited bottom_sheet.dart file and added -75.0 in this part of the code

```
      @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    return Offset(0.0, size.height - childSize.height * progress - 75.0);
  }
```

That did the trick, however, the animation still starts from the bottom. Not sure If I like it or not.